# robocopy and thumbs.db

Tags: windows-7

i am trying to backup some files from the network from one folder to another.
a thumbs.db keeps popping up and the process cannot complete, it keeps saying waiting for 30 seconds and so on.
how do I re-write the code to only copy pdf files or skip the thumb.db file?

also is it advisable to use MIR for simple copy functions? too many switches to choose from....
this didn't work. but without the pdf commands it was working. thanks for your help in advance.

```
robocopy "\\usfile01\US-ID-COMMON\VisualMgmt\Production Boards\Daily *.pdf" "\\usfile01\US-ID-COMMON\VisualMgmt\Production Boards\Monthly *.pdf" /MIR
```

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
robocopy "\\usfile01\US-ID-COMMON\VisualMgmt\Production Boards\Daily" "\\usfile01\US-ID-COMMON\VisualMgmt\Production Boards\Monthly" /XF thumb.db /MIR
```

> XF is listed as '/XF file [file]... :: eXclude Files matching given
>   names/paths/wildcards.' in `robocopy /?`

Comment: Same problem. Solution Works! It's probably Thumb*s*.db though.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the question we have a couple of options:

"it keeps saying waiting for 30 seconds and so on"
For this you can adjust the wait settings with /w:1 to wait 1 second for example, and the retry settings /r:1 to only retry 1 time when it encounters an error.  This will allow it to move past errors more quickly.

"how do I re-write the code to only copy pdf files"
you had it right with the *.pdf flag, but you only need to specify it once, after the source and destination have been specified, so the command becomes:
robocopy "\usfile01\US-ID-COMMON\VisualMgmt\Production Boards\daily" "\usfile01\US-ID-COMMON\VisualMgmt\Production Boards\monthly" *.pdf /MIR

"or skip the thumb.db file?"
Previous answer of using "/XF thumbs.db" (without quotes in the command string) is correct to exclude the thumbs.db file.

LAST BIT OF ADVICE HERE:
"also is it advisable to use MIR for simple copy functions?"
Possible? Yes.  Advisable? No.  /MIR will copy the source and destination exactly.  If you have files in your destination that don't exist in your source, they will be deleted as "extras" in your logs, without warning.  Just to move some files around, don't use /MIR.